# Evaluate $\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{1/\sqrt 2}\int_{z=r}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}r\text d z \text d r\text d \theta$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> I need to evaluate
>
> $$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{1/\sqrt 2}\int_{z=r}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}r\text d z \text d r\text d \theta$$

**My attempt:**

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{1/\sqrt 2} \left(r\sqrt{1-r^2}-r\right)\text d r\text d \theta=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}-\frac 1 3\left(1-1/\sqrt 2-1/\sqrt 2\right)\text d \theta=2\pi\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}-\frac 1 3\right)$$

1. Is it correct?
2. I need to find the shap of this, e.g prism, cone etc how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your first step. I reckon it should be

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{1/\sqrt 2} r\left(\sqrt{1-r^2}-r\right)\text d r$$

To find the shape, note this is in cylindrical coordinates. $\theta$ goes all around, $r$ goes from 0 to $1/\sqrt 2$. The height component spans from $r$ to $\sqrt{1-r^2}$. What do those surfaces look like?

Comment: Is this a cone?

Comment: @Error404 If $r=0$, $z\in [0,1]$. But if $r=1/\sqrt 2$, $z=1/\sqrt 2$. With a cone, however, the height is constant. But it is close. It helps to plug in values and plot what you get on paper.